# How to dynamically pass the different time on setInterval() method in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Code :

```
class Schedule extends Component {
   state = {
      new_date: null
   }
   componentDidMount() {
      var start = new Date().getMinutes()
      var end = 24
      var diff = end - start
      var interval = setInterval(() => {
         this.setState({
            new_date: new Date()
         })
      }, diff)
     interval()
   }
}
```

Here all i want is to pass different timer value on each page refresh or specific condition is satisfied 
Suppose when i refresh the page i will have new date and i want to subtract new date from end and here i can get suppose diff == 5000 millisecond.

But the problem is after the timer has executed i want to again find new date in the variable start and substract it from variable end so that i will have different value in variable diff and thus different timer value and above code cannot update the value of variable start.
It would be great help if somebody could help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clear interval if you want to change the time

```
let interval

class Schedule extends Component {
   runInterval: (time) => {
     if (interval) {
       clearInterval(interval)
       interval = null
     }

     interval = setInterval(() => {
         // do something in here and you have also a new time
         // pass new time to run interval function to have interval with new 
         // time
         this.runInterval(3000) // 3000 is an example of a new time
      }, intervalPeriod)
   }
   componentDidMount() {
      var start = new Date().getMinutes()
      var end = 24
      var diff = end - start

      this.runInterval(diff)
   }
}
```

Comment: i didn't understand why variable interval is declared outside of class.All want to achieve is when a setinterval() first cycle completes i want to get new date suppose before entering into setinterval suppose i got var start = 25 minute and when i subtract with var end i got 4 second and that 4 second is passed as timer to setInterval() and after 4 second i want to update the var start which is current new date and here in this case may be var start = 25minute + 4 sec = new date after first setInterval() cycle

Comment: you should reset interval if you want to change the time, interval variable should be outside of function to be able to track, you need more training in JavaScript

Comment: i think you didn't understand what i was trying to do .I want to update the variable after each setInterval cycle so that i could get different timer dynamically.The componentdidmount() runs only once and i am not able to update variable start so my question is how to achieve that so i could have different timer value

Comment: @SurajGhale I updated the answer, whenever you want to start interval with new period just run the function with new period as parameter, there is no need to store the period in react state as you can see in the example

Comment: @SurajGhale you're welcome if my answer helped you, please hit the check mark beside the answer thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use setTimeout and in this timeout call again setTimeout with different time value

```
var time = 1000;
function recursion(){
    time = 2000;
    setTimeout(function(){  
      recursion();
    },time);
}

recursion();
```

Comment: thanks for the help sir but i all want to achieve is when a setinterval() first cycle completes  i want to get new date suppose before entering into setinterval suppose i got var start = 25 minute and when i subtract with var end i got 4 second and that 4 second  is passed as timer to setInterval() and after 4 second i want to update the var start which is current new date and here in this case may be var start = 25minute + 4 sec = new date after first setInterval() cycle